# How to run a program once CPU/Memory reaches a certain %?

Tags: windows-10, memory, cpu, script

Simply put I have a very VERY useful program let's call it "Bigbro" that needs to run 24/7, I have made a script with macro recorder to automatically kills all instances of BigBro and another script that starts all instances of BigBro (it needs to be logged into which I have a script doing that for me by its self).

The problem I am running into is that BigBro likes to memory leak, sometimes after an hour of running, sometimes after 5 hours..I could just forcibly restart it every hour but then I won't be able to use my PC as I will have a script that will basically always be on. I could do task manager but again it's disruptive, I would like to only kill BigBro when its hitting atleast 30% of CPU usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Task Scheduler service has the ability to run a scheduled task based on other conditions besides a specific time. It's possible to [run a task when a specific event appears in the Event log](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748841(v=ws.11).aspx). If the program in question creates any errors in the event log when it starts acting up, you can use one of those to trigger your script.

The Windows Performance Monitor tool can also give you a way to monitor for specific performance conditions and trigger events based on them. 
You can create a performance monitor data collector and then create an alert based on various performance items, including CPU utilization, network bandwidth, memory consumption, etc. An [introduction to using Perfmon can be found here.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744567(v=ws.10).aspx) The instructio1ns mention server 2012 and Windows 7, but Perfmon in Windows 10 is pretty similar.

These alerts can be used to write an item in the application event log, which can in turn trigger a scheduled task, or it can directly run a specific WMI task when the alert occurs.